# Migrating Sharepoint2010 from Old server To new Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, migration, backup, restore

I have Sharepoint2010 Enterprise, and SQL2008 on Windows Server2008R2.

I'm new to sharepoint Platform, im trying to move sharepoint 2010 from old server to new server.

On existing Sharepoint2010(Old Server) I have One Site collection on a Web app, lets say ABC on  Sharepoint-80 Webapp.

I have installed Standalone Sharepoint2010 on new server.
Do i need to create a site on New sharepoint2010 and restore the sitecollection backup?
If yes how do i dot it with powershell? Can i restore with SQL backups?

I have tried Restoring Sitecollection backup on new server(**Test Environment**) from Powershell but it gives me an error saying

> PS C:\Users\Administrator> Restore-SPSite http://win-7ts0u9r9dai:8080/sites/Tcs
>   -Path Site C:\Soft\SP backups\Site collectionSiteCollection.bak -Force
>   Restore-SPSite : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '
>   C:\Soft\SP'.
>   At line:1 char:15
>   + Restore-SPSite <<<<  http://win-7ts0u9r9dai:8080/sites/Tcs -Path Site C:\Soft
>   \SP backups\Site collectionSiteCollection.bak -Force
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Restore-SPSite], Parameter
>      BindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.SharePoint
>      .PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreSite

I want to restore total SP and settings.
Please Explain me how to move sharepoint 2010 to new server in **Plain English.**
(plz Correct me if i'm wrong)

Thanx in advance.

Comment: The path you're using in your command has a space in it. Try putting the path within double quotes -Path "C:\Soft\SP backups\Site collectionSiteCollection.bak"

Answer (score 3):

The best way to perform the migration is to use the database attach method. You can do this by backing up the database and log files, restoring them onto the new SQL server, then attaching them to the web application they are to be used with.
See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628582(v=office.14).aspx for information on how to perform these actions.
You're better off using PowerShell for the database attach as that seems to be more reliable. Note also that your new farm need sot be on the same patch level (recommended) or above when attaching the databases to it.

Answer (score 1):

We can have automated backup strategies to backup the required contents on intervals.

The Backup and Restore settings can be accessed from SharePoint Central Administration.

For performing a manual backup, use the >Perform a backup link . In the appearing page, select the items you need to backup and click the >Next button. Depending on the item the backup size will increase.

In the >next page of the backup wizard, enter the >backup type and location.

Click the >Start Backup button to perform the backup. Make sure you set the location shared access to Everyone.

Wait for a few while to complete the operation.

**Note**
If the Backup page says the Administrative service is not running, you need to start it manually from Windows Services.

Use the Run window to execute the command services.msc. In the appearing applet, >right click and start the SharePoint 2010 Administration service.

**Restore**
We can restore a farm, site, or the backed up item using the >Restore from a backup option.

In >next page select the >radio button of the appropriate backup and click the >Next button.

we have to choose backup location.

In the >next page select the >components to restore.

Click the >Next button and the restore operation gets started.

Answer (score 0):

As you already build the new Server, it is easy to move the data.

1. Make Sure your new farm is on the same built /version level as the old is
2. create the web application n new farm
3. If you have any customization, please deploy it
4. Set the proper permission on SQL server.
5. If you are using any service application, please create those as well i.e search, upa
6. Now Backup the Content Database from the OLD farm and Restore it to new Farm SQL Server.
7. Detach the existing the Content DB from Newly Create web App( which was created during the new web app). and attach the newly restored DB.
8. Test it.